# How to use functions to define subscript/superscript in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to format the subscript for the text in Excel. As I have many texts, I want to do it in batch. Can I ask is there a function to convert the text to subscript?

I would like to use functions, not hotkeys.

For example, convert **VL** to **V<sub>L</sub>**.

Comment: Functions can only return values. You will need to write a VBA macro to accomplish your goal.

Comment: Someone has already done that below.  And if you didn't want to have to push a button or manually trigger the macro, you could use an event-triggered macro (eg `worksheet_change`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achive this you could write a macro and then run it from the developer tab.
*For more information on how to run a macro or enable developer tools see [the support page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/run-a-macro-5e855fd2-02d1-45f5-90a3-50e645fe3155)*

```vb
'You can make the first character in the A1 cell subscript like this
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Characters(0, 1).Font.Subscript = True
```

**Extended example**

```vb
Sub SubscriptWithRegex()
    'Create a new regex object, import reference from
    'Tools > References > Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
    Set regex = New RegExp
    'Define the pattern, use regexr.com to test and write regex
    'For this example we will subscript all L characters after a V
    regex.Pattern = "V(L+)"
    'if TRUE, find all matches, if FALSE find only the first match
    regex.Global = True
    'Iterate trough cells in Sheet1 range A1:A6
    For Each cell In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A6")
        'Search for the pattern
        Set matches = regex.Execute(cell.Value)
        'Iterate trough the matches
        For Each Match In matches
            'Make characters subscript
            'We need to shift the match to left by 2 to skip the V character
            'and we need to subtract that single V from the total length
            cell.Characters(Match.FirstIndex + 2, Match.Length - 1).Font.Subscript = True
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Before and after running the macro

```
+----------+----------+
| Before   | After    |
+---+------+---+------+
|   | A    |   | A    |
+---+------+---+------+
| 1 | VLLL | 1 | VLLL |
+---+------+---+------+
| 2 | VL   | 2 | VL   |
+---+------+---+------+
| 3 | VVLL | 3 | VVLL |
+---+------+---+------+
| 4 | VLVL | 4 | VLVL |
+---+------+---+------+
| 5 | LLL  | 5 | LLL  |
+---+------+---+------+
| 6 | V    | 6 | V    |
+---+------+---+------+
```

**References**
[Excel VBA reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/excel)
[Font object (Excel)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.font(object))
[Characters object (Excel)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.characters)